# What are the relative pros and cons of a Pentax K1000 or Nikon F for getting into film photography?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, film, slr, pentax-k1000

I want to get into film photography and go back to the roots to really learn about the techniques. Would you guys recommend the **Pentax K1000** or the **Nikon F**, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is fine, but: The Nikon F is heavier and bulkier, and you have to take the back off to load the film. I can think of many fine film cameras I would rather have than a Nikon F. The Olympus OM-1 or OM-2 are good cameras, and the lenses are excellent. The Leicaflex SL is also a good choice, and many superb lenses are available for it. I would take either of these systems over the Nikon F.

The K1000 is a good camera, by the way, but I would prefer the Olympus or Leicaflex systems. I own the latter.

Comment: Which ones would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 0):

Spend a few dollars more for an F2. Keh.com is a great place for these. Make sure you are buying one with a photomic prism, he have meters. Also read the review on Ken Rockwell's website and find the manual online. These will also tell you what battery your camera needs for the meter.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why you recommend one over the other?